# Why are my TransactionScopes not being respected during testing?

Tags: c#, transactions, integration-testing, transactionscope

Given the following:

```
public class TestEnvironment
{

  private static TransactionScope scope;

  [AssemblyInitialize]
  public static void Init(TestContext context) 
  {

    /* establish database connection, create Session fake, create Items fake, etc. */

    scope = new TransactionScope();

  }

  [AssemblyCleanup]
  public static void Cleanup()
  {
    scope.Dispose();
  }
}
```

I'm seeing test data show up in the database. And I'm seeing the following in an error in the test output:

> A TransactionScope must be disposed in the same thread that created
>   it.

This occurs only when ALL tests are run. When any given test is run individually, there's no problem.

If I remove the `scope.Dispose()` call, allowing the scope to be disposed "naturally", the error vanishes, but I still see records accumulate in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Without speaking too much to how `TransactionScope` works with threads (because I'm ignorant on the matter), the problem has been resolved by creating the scopes during the instantiation of each `TestClass`.

To save a handful of keystrokes, we created a `ScopedTestClass` class:

```
public class ScopedTestClass : IDisposable
{
  private TransactionScope TxnScope;
  public ScopedTestClass()
  {
    TxnScope = new TransactionScope();
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    TsnScope.Dispose();
  }
}
```

And each `TestClass` inherits from that:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass : ScopedTestClass
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // sanity at last!
  }
}
```

And everything is good.